# Opensource bus route planner

Tags: software-recommendations, open-source-gis, routing, general-transit-feed-specification, transit

Since I have little coding skills, I'm looking for an open source bus route planner that consumes GTFS data (That I have to create myself), All I could find was OpenRouteService, and although it has some pretty nice features, the bus routing informations are very lacking (no bus numbers, stations name, transit...), Looking for something similar to Google Transit.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't mention if you want to run the program locally or have it hosted.

[OpenTripPlanner](http://opentripplanner.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is the best open-source option in terms of getting up and running quickly, with a slight learning curve.

There is a hosted product called [Coord](https://coord.co/) which has a free tier.

Comment: Locally, I dowloaded OpenTripPlanner from GitHub but the index.html in "OpenTripPlanner-master/src/client" gives me so many errors (XML and Reference errors) that I have no idea how to resolve.

Comment: Take a look at the tutorial ( http://opentripplanner.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Basic-Tutorial/ ) , you'll need to run the JAR file, not the plain source code.

Answer (score 0):

I have no knowledge about any specific open source route planning algorithm, but I have recently seen a list of route plannig programs which can use GTFS: Maybe one of them is open source or free. Have a look in the section 'Applications Based on GTFS' --> ' Trip planning and Maps'
https://www.transitwiki.org/TransitWiki/index.php/General_Transit_Feed_Specification#cite_note-15